# How to add multiple entities to store using ngrx/data saveEntities?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-data

I am trying to add multiple entities to the store using ngrx/data -> saveEntities. So far I got this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MaintenanceEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Maintenance> {

  constructor(
    private serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
    private entityCacheDispatcher: EntityCacheDispatcher) {
    super('Maintenance', serviceElementsFactory);
  }

  addBatch(maintenances: Maintenance[]) {
    const changes: ChangeSetItem[] = [
      cif.add('Maintenance', maintenances)
    ];
    const changeSet: ChangeSet = { changes, tag: 'Creating alert batch'};

    return this.entityCacheDispatcher.saveEntities(changeSet, `${environment.API}maintenances`).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    );
  }
}
```

My endpoint receives and return an object like this:

```
interface ChangeSet<T = any> {
  changes: ChangeSetItem[]
  extras?: T
  tag?: string
}
```

In the backend I insert all entities into the database and then before returning the same object I update ids, but once again **in the Angular app, the store is not getting updated**. Am I missing something?

https://ngrx.io/api/data/EntityCacheDispatcher#saveentities

Comment: maybe you could call `this.addManyToCache(changeSet)` in the `pipe`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the `ChangeSet` object has a property called `ChangeSetItem` with the next structure:

```
type ChangeSetItem = ChangeSetAdd | ChangeSetDelete | ChangeSetUpdate | ChangeSetUpsert;

interface ChangeSetAdd<T = any> {
  op: ChangeSetOperation.Add
  entityName: string
  entities: T[]
}
```

So I need to return the corresponding `entityName` from the backend so it can be added to the store: In my case: **Maintenance**

Not sure why the property is not being set in this line:

```
const changes: ChangeSetItem[] = [
      cif.add('Maintenance', maintenances)
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `entityName` on the `ChangeSet` when you create it.

```
const changeSet: ChangeSet = { 
    entityName: 'Maintenance',
    changes, 
    tag: 'Creating alert batch'
};
```

This should ensure it's there for the full round trip.  Its not clear from your example what `cif` is but it seems it will only apply to the `ChangeSetItem`, not the `ChangeSet`.

Secondly, though this may not concern you, if your server is assigning id's to your saved entities, you need *Pessimistic* saves enabled - this can be done at various extension points.  If Optimistic save is enabled, I don't think ngrx does anything with your ChangeSet on success - eg. New ids would not be assigned to new entities.